Not getting performance improvement with AVX in comparison with SSE
I am trying to utilise SIMD capabilities of processor. However, in case of vectorisation I observed that there is no improvement while compiling binary for AVX(cmake flag -mavx2) when compared with binary compiled for SSE(cmake flag -msse).
I was expecting around 1.5 times improvement with AVX, but it is clearly not the case. Could anyone please help me with why is it behaving this way ?
Below is the POC code I am testing :
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>
#include <vector>
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <malloc.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace chrono;

std::string generateRandomString(size_t length) {
    // Define the characters to be used in the random string
    const std::string characters =
            "0123456789"
            "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
            "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
            "!@#$%^&*()_+[]{}|;:,.<>?";

    // Initialize random number generator
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 generator(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> distribution(0, characters.size() - 1);

    // Generate the random string
    std::string randomString;
    randomString.reserve(length); // Reserve space to avoid multiple allocations

    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        randomString += characters[distribution(generator)];
    }

    return randomString;
}

void test_int_vectorization(int32_t size) {
    uint64_t* array1 = new uint64_t[size];
    uint64_t* array2 = new uint64_t[size];
    uint64_t* result = new uint64_t[size];

    auto t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        array1[i] = 1000 + i;
        array2[i] = 500 + i;
    }

    auto t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto populationTime = duration_cast<milliseconds>(t2 - t1);
    cout << "Time in populating arrays = " << to_string(populationTime.count()) << " ms \n";

    t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        result[i] = array1[i] + array2[i];
    }

    auto t3 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto operation_duration = duration_cast<milliseconds>(t3 - t2);
    std::cout << "Int operation : Add completed in " << to_string(operation_duration.count()) << " ms \n";

    t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        result[i] = array1[i] * array2[i];
    }

    t3 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    operation_duration = duration_cast<milliseconds>(t3 - t2);
    std::cout << "Int operation : Multiply completed in " << to_string(operation_duration.count()) << " ms \n";

    t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        result[i] = array1[i] / array2[i];
    }

    t3 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    operation_duration = duration_cast<milliseconds>(t3 - t2);
    std::cout << "Int operation : Division completed in " << to_string(operation_duration.count()) << " ms \n";

    t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        result[i] = array1[i] % array2[i];
    }

    t3 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    operation_duration = duration_cast<milliseconds>(t3 - t2);
    std::cout << "Int operation : Modulo completed in " << to_string(operation_duration.count()) << " ms \n";
}

void test_string_vectorization(int size) {
    string randStr1 = generateRandomString(size);
    string randStr2 = generateRandomString(size);

    vector<bool> areSame(size);

    auto t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        areSame[i] = randStr1[i] == randStr2[i];
    }
    auto t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();

    auto operation_duration = duration_cast<milliseconds>(t2 - t1);
    cout << "String operation completed in " << to_string(operation_duration.count()) << " ms \n";
}

int main() {

    int32_t size = 409600000;
    test_int_vectorization(size);
    test_string_vectorization(size);

    return 0;
}

When created binary for SSE and AVX, below are the numbers I am getting
// AVX - 

Time in populating arrays = 1586 ms 
Int operation : Add completed in 976 ms 
Int operation : Multiply completed in 447 ms 
Int operation : Division completed in 963 ms 
Int operation : Modulo completed in 961 ms 
String operation completed in 558 ms 

// SSE - 
Time in populating arrays = 1539 ms 
Int operation : Add completed in 947 ms 
Int operation : Multiply completed in 449 ms 
Int operation : Division completed in 959 ms 
Int operation : Modulo completed in 958 ms 
String operation completed in 517 ms 


What hardware (some basically split AVX operations as 2 SSE ops)? Side remark: it often helps vectorizers if all numbers have the same size, array1[i] = 1000 + i mixes 64 bits and 32 bits.

Besides your hardware, can you post your compiler version and full compilation options (if you don't use -O3 or related, the compiler won't auto-vectorize). Overall, your problem looks more bottle-necked by memory-throughput (though this won't explain why addition takes longer than multiplication).

By the way, high_resolution_clock is at best useless and at worst dangerous to measure time span. Please do not use it. The author itself advise not to use it.

Since you are relying on auto-vectorization, it would be prudent to inspect disassembler of your code. Simply passing -mavx2 does not guarantee that the compiler actually uses 256-bit vectors in the generated code. You may also need to pass other options, in particular -march, to let the compiler know that 256-bit vectors are actually beneficial for performance on the target CPUs. There may be also factors in your code that prevent the compiler from using 256-bit vectors or even vectorizing it at all.

@chtz: This benchmark measures add taking longer than mul because add is tested first, and is the first loop to touch result, so it's paying for the cost of the page-faults.  (And any other warm-up effects like CPU frequency.)  Idiomatic way of performance evaluation?   has some links with more detail.  This is also partly why the "populating arrays" loop is so slow.

What compiler is this? If this is gcc, it won't auto-vectorize below -O3, unless -ftree-vectorize is added. -mavx2 and -msse (as well as -march=...) do not vectorize, they enable the compiler to use respective instructions.
Depending on the CPU, it might be further beneficial to align your arrays on 32-byte or better cache line boundaries (64 bytes) and tell the compiler so.
A simple way to tell the compiler to try to vectorize and add alignment hints is pragma omp simd for compilers that support it (e.g. clang, gcc, Intel).
To see what the compiler vectorized and what not, respective reports are useful (-fopt-info-vec for GCC).
